# select sql many-to-many relationship into nested php object

Tags: php, sql, many-to-many, firebird

**problem**

I have two data tables `SEQUENCES` and `ORGANISMS` whose many-to-many-relationship is mappend in the table `SOURCES`. There is also a 1-m relationshipt between `SOURCES` and `ENTRIES`. I will append a detailed structure.

What i want to achieve, is the display of all sequences with all associated organisms and entries, where a condition within the sequences table is met. I have some ideas on how to achieve this, but i need the solution with the best performance, as each of these contains 50k+ entries.

**idea one**

Select all organisms that belong to the same sequence as a concatenated string in sql, and split it in PHP. I have no idea though, how to do the concatenation in SQL.

**idea two**

select same sequences with different organisms as distinct records, order by organism, and join them later in php. though this somehow feels just wrong.

**idea three**

use views. ANY idea on this one appreciated

**structure**

```
SEQUENCES
  SEQUENCE_ID
  DESCRIPTION

ORGANISMS
  ORGANISM_ID
  NAME

SOURCES
  SOURCE_ID
  SEQUENCE_ID FK to SEQUENCES.SEQUENCE_ID
  ORGANISM_ID FK to ORGANISMS.ORGANISM_ID

ENTRIES
  SOURCE_ID FK to SOURCES.SOURCE_ID
  ENTRY_VALUE
```

**desired outcome**

```
array(
  array(
    "SEQUENCE_ID" => 4,
    "DESCRIPTION" => "Some sequence",
    "SOURCES" => array(
      array(
        "ORGANISM_ID" => 562,
        "ORGANISM_NAME" => "Escherichia coli",
        "ENTRIES" => array(
          "some entry",
          "some other entry"
        ),
      array(
        "ORGANISM_ID" => 402764,
        "ORGANISM_NAME" => "Aranicola sp. EP18",
        "ENTRIES" => array()
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    "SEQUENCE_ID" => 5,
    .....
  )
)
```

**PHP5 and FIREBIRD2.5.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fetch a nested array like that directly from a flat table structure. But if I get you right, what you want to do is not that hard to achieve.

I don't understand why you would concatenate things and then split them again, that's hard to maintain and probably slow.

I see two approaches here:

1. Fetch everything at once as flat table using JOIN and loop through it in PHP. This approach creates a lot of duplication but it's fast because you can fetch all data in one query and then process it with PHP.
2. Fetch every entity separately, loop and fetch the next hierarchy level as you go. This approach will be slower. It takes complexity away from the SQL query and doesn't fetch redunant data. It also gives you more freedom as to how you loop through your data and what you do with it.

Alternatively you might want to actually store hierarchical data in a no-sql way, where you could already store the array structure you mentioned.

Comment: yeah i thought about nosql dbs like mongo, but sadly, i have to stay with firebird, as it is 'robust' and 'has been around for decades'. your first approach matches my second idea, which didn't seem quite right to me, but maybe i should try it. i have thought of your second approach, too, but forgot to mention it, thanks.

Comment: The first approach doesn't sound right because of the redundancies, but in the end it's not something that creates technical debt and it's faster. Nesting database calls is not exactly good practice either. Fetch all the data you need for a particular view and then deal with it. You could of course cash the tables and query them from the cash.